# How can I make an intro screen in Android that ends after a click?

Tags: java, android, click, splash-screen

How can I make an intro screen in Android, that when the app starts it stands there for as long as there is not a click on the screen, and then to kill itself?
I made the layout with the picture, made a java class for it, but don't know what methods to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:id="@+id/linear_splash"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"
    >

    </LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
LinearLayout LL;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LL=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linear_splash);
    LL.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,Second.class);
            finish();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: Actually, no, this is not working at all, here, please take a look and tell me whats wrong, it force closes the moment it starts...
- This is the intro class - [link](http://pastebin.com/P8k2N2J0)
- This is the book game class (the actual class that the app will work in) - [link](http://pastebin.com/ggrSd8Ef)
- This is the intro layout - [link](http://pastebin.com/x9dV8e31)
- This is the layout of the book class - [link](http://pastebin.com/CqtHMxnT)
- This is the manifest - [link](http://pastebin.com/s8f9ZsfD)

Comment: in this link http://pastebin.com/ggrSd8Ef
change  setContentView(R.id.knigata); with 
setContentView(R.layout.knigata);   

& in this link http://pastebin.com/x9dV8e31

you should have image in drawable so you can use it if you didn't put image delete this  android:background="@drawable/wallpaper"

Comment: In the first thing I changed the setContentView with (R.layout.bookscreen), because this is the layout of the app, and about the second thing you suggested, yes, I have the image in the drawable folder named wallpaper...
aaaand crashes again....

Comment: there you go, http://pastebin.com/Hz0LHsjD
EDIT: weird, I changed the relative layout to lienar layout and now at least the intro screen showed up, and when I clicked it got another force close...

Comment: I think it's something to do with the imports, both java class have
import com.example.knigaigra2.R;
and the project isn't even named that way, it's
com.book.game

Comment: i think you put each activity in different pacakge 
 com.book.game.IntroScreen

com.example.knigaigra2
move this activity  knigaigra2 to  the first package  

and delete import com.example.knigaigra2.R;

in this link  http://pastebin.com/ggrSd8Ef

Comment: I did it, earlier I made a Refactor and renamed the classes and the layouts, but the old name of the package was still written in the manifest, I changed it there, deleted the imports with the .R at the end, changed the setContentView to (R.layout.bookscreen) and now worked fine.
My only question is why the setContentView doesn't work if I make it with ID (R.id.knigata), it's the exact ID of the bookscreen.xml and it's not workin this way... Why?

Answer (score 2):

You can just make an activity with your splash screen as the background image. Set the `android:onClick` attribute to a method, which starts a new activity.

**Update**:

I like the idea of using only a separate layout, because you don't need to make an additional activity. I wouldn't use a button however, because usually you want to tap the screen without any animation, like pressing and releasing. You still use the `android:onClick` attribute on the layout

Splash screen layout:

```
<View xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background "@drawable/splash_screen"
    android:onClick "removeSplash"
    android:clickable "true"
    ...
    />
```

and in the method called you just replace the splash layout with the main activity layout

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen);
    ...
}

public void removeSplash(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // any other initialization needed
}
```

Comment: how about to make a new layout with a single button taking up the whole screen, and to have a background the Intro screen, and when it's pressed to kill that activity and start the main one? How cna I do that

Comment: @БориславМинчев Yes, this is a very good idea actually. Please see updated answer.

Comment: nothing happens... again, here's what I want:
- there's a layout with a picture that will serve as an intro screen
- if there's a click on the screen, that layout and class will be killed, and the main class will start

Comment: @БориславМинчев You must set the splash screen in `onCreate` and maybe use the `android:clickable` attribute as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to make it simple, a custom dialog should be quick made, and you don't have to create another activity.